# Any homomorphism from $GL(n, F)$ to $F$ is composition of $det$ and $F$-endomorphism.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, determinant, general-linear-group

I found statement of theorem, that for any field $F$, any homomorphism $f:GL(n, F)\rightarrow F^{*}$ is composition $f=g\circ det$ for some $g:F^{*}\rightarrow F^{*}$ - endomorphism, and $det$ - determinant. But i could'n find proof of that theorem, could you help?

Comment: Homomorphism of what?

Comment: @azif00 of general linear group over F and F* - multiplicative group of F

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Álvarez, but how is determinant coming out here?